# Dojo DataGrid: Doesnot sort images in a column

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have written a code for dojo datagrid column which contains images.

Code:
formatter: function(cellValue, rowIndex){

```
    if(data.items[rowIndex].status == "COMPLETED"){
          return "<img src='app/img/dot_done.png' />"+ " " +cellValue; 
    }
        else if(data.items[rowIndex].status == "IN_PROGRESS"){
          return "<img src='app/img/dot_in_progress.png' />"+" " +cellValue; 
    }
       }
```

output is:
Before sorting:

```
      (done.img) complete

      (block.img) block

       (done.img) complete

       (block.img) block
```

After Sorting:

```
       (done.img) block

       (block.img) block

       (done.img) complete

       (block.img) complete
```

So, for the above code, it is not sorting images but the cellvalues are sorted.

Could any one suggest me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

I am adding code here:

```
    var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data}); 

var layout = [[

{'name': 'TaskName', 'field': 'task_name', 'width': '20%',styles: 'text-align: center;'},


{'name': 'Status', 'field': 'status', 'width': '15%', styles: 'text-align: center;',

      formatter: function(cellValue, rowIndex){

                if(data.items[rowIndex].status == "COMPLETED"){ 

                    return "<img src='app/img/dot_done.png' />"+ " " +cellValue; } 

                }}]]; 

        var grid = new DataGrid({

                 id: 'grid', store: store, structure: layout, 

             });

        grid.placeAt("newdiv");

        grid.startup();
```

Comment: can you check on firebug if separate columns are getting created for image name and the cellvalues

Comment: Also where is the "cellvalue" getting calculated..can u share the code ?

Comment: var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});  

 var layout = [[{'name': 'TaskName', 'field': 'task_name', 'width': '20%',styles: 'text-align: center;'},  
{'name': 'Status', 'field': 'status', 'width': '15%', styles: 'text-align: center;',  
 formatter: function(cellValue, rowIndex){  
                           if(data.items[rowIndex].status == "COMPLETED"){  
 return "<img src='app/img/dot_done.png' />"+ " " +cellValue; 
}  
/* previous code */
}}]];  
  
var grid = new DataGrid({
 id: 'grid',
 store: store,
 structure: layout, });
 grid.placeAt("newdiv");
 grid.startup();

Comment: I cannot format the code. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: you can edit your post and add the code (+format) :)

Comment: I have edited, formatted and added code for the question :)

Comment: hey..whats ths variable "cellValue" you are passing to the formatter ?

Comment: Value is got form datastore. and it is passed to formatter by dojo datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stackoverflow answer that should solve your problem:

[How to sort a dojo datagrid cell correctly when formatter accesses other row content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359539/how-to-sort-a-dojo-datagrid-cell-correctly-when-formatter-accesses-other-row-con)

Comment: isn't this the same problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the bug. Instead of datastore I have to use cellValue to compare the values.

```
 function(cellValue, rowIndex){

    if(cellValue == "COMPLETED"){
          return "<img src='app/img/dot_done.png' />"+ " " +cellValue; 
    }
        else if(cellValue == "IN_PROGRESS"){
          return "<img src='app/img/dot_in_progress.png' />"+" " +cellValue; 
    }
       }
```